# How to append two SearchDescriptors in NEST

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am taking input from a client to build up an elasticsearch query using NEST.  I start out with the basics, like so:

```
var search = esClient.Search<MyData>(s => s
    .From(pageNum * pageSize)
    .Take(pageSize)
    .QueryRaw(@"{""match_all"": {} }")
```

I then parse out the request and see if an optional sorting parameter was passed in.  If it was, I create a new `SearchDescriptor<MyData>()` which performs that requested sort, and I want to add it to my original `search` criteria.  Obviously `.Search()` will actually perform an HTTP call, so it can't happen as it is today, but how can I stick a series of `SearchDescriptor` calls together and then perform the search at the end?

Comment: Could you please describe the sort of parameters that you wish to incorporate into your search? ES and Nest allow for a ton of customization which you can add onto the call, more info is needed as to what you wish to implement.

Comment: @DanielHoffmann-Mitscherling Well, the user will pass in a query string for us to drop into `QueryRaw`, but will also (optionally) pass in a separate string representing the field to be sorted on, and a separate string representing the order to sort in (asc/desc).  Finally, a facet type and what to facet on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can build `SearchDescriptor` incrementally as under. I've used aggregations instead of facets (which are deprecated now) but I hope you get the idea.

```
var sd = new SearchDescriptor<MyData>();

sd = sd.QueryRaw(<raw query string>);

if (<should sort>)
{
    string fieldToBeSortedOn; // input from user
    bool sortInAscendingOrder; // input from user
    if (sortInAscendingOrder)
    {
        sd = sd.Sort(f => f
            .Ascending()
            .OnField(fieldToBeSortedOn));
    }
    else
    {
        sd = sd.Sort(f => f
            .Descending()
            .OnField(fieldToBeSortedOn));
    }
}

if (<should compute aggregations>)
{
    sd = sd.Aggregations(a => a
        .Terms(
            "term_aggs", 
            t => t
                .Field(<name of field to compute terms aggregation on>)));
}

var search = esClient.Search<MyData>(s => sd);
```